# find the value not present in the column earlier

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looking to find the latest scanids which doesn't have an errorid present from the previous scan.

```
scanid  | errorid | date                |state
--------|---------|---------------------|-----
   1    |    1    | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 9
   1    |    2    | 2016-01-01 00:00:00 | 9
   2    |    1    | 2016-01-02 00:00:00 | 9
```

For the example above, I want to display below row as result:

```
scanid  | errorid | date                |state
--------|---------|---------------------|-----
   2    |    2    | 2016-01-02 00:00:00 | 10
```

So, errorid 2 is not repeated with scanid 2, also I need to change the state of this row to 10 for the errorid 2 which is not part of the latest scan.

I have tried using NOT IN and EXISTS but not getting expected record.

I am using PostgreSQL as my database.

Comment: so every scanid has to be checked against the previous one and the missing errorid should be the result..is that correct?

Comment: That's exactly what I want

Comment: @hadooper . . . I don't get it.  There is no row like the one you specified in the data.  What is the "previous scan"?  What happens when there are multiple errors, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5?

Comment: @GordonLinoff You have to hard code the `state` value to get the result

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Here I am worried about the errors which are previously occurred. In this case errors 1,2 occurred before in scanid 1 and in scanid 2 I see only errorid 1.
If there are multiple errors in scanid 2 then we are fine, we need to look for the errors which are part of last scan and not part of this scan.

Comment: Do you have an `id` column to uniquely identify the records?

Answer (score 0):

To find the highest and second highest scan IDs rank them with `DENSE_RANK`. Then use a `NOT EXISTS` clause to get the last scan records that have no match in the previous scan.

```
with ranked as
(
  select
    scanid, errorid, date, state, dense_rank() over(order by scanid desc) as rnk
  from scans
)
select scanid, errorid, date, state + 1
from ranked lastscan
where rnk = 1
and not exists
(
  select *
  from ranked prevscan
  where prevscan.rnk = 2
  and prevscan.errorid = lastscan.errorid
);
```